# Magento 2.3 Translation Theme Problems

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Im using a magento 2.3 recently migrated from magento 1.9.3.

I installed a theme in it (argento theme) and installed a pt_BR translation pack by composer (https://github.com/rafaelstz/traducao_magento2_pt_br/)

The problem is that a few stuff in my website were translated and other stuff were not. For example: In product page there is DETAILS (untranslated) and Avaliações (translated). In home page there is SHOP SALE untranslated.

I tried to add the remaining untranslated stuff in pt_BR.csv (/web-site/vendor/rafaelstz/traducao_magento2_pt_br) and it doesn't work.

I tried to add in app/design/frontend/magento but the folder is empty;

i tried to create a folder app/i18n/ and scan for words and it didn't worked;

I tried entering folder: /mage2.abaraujo.com/pub/static/frontend/Swissup/argento-pure2/pt_BR and entering respective extensions and change. It doesn't worked.

What should i do?

Thanks
Lucas

Comment: Could you show the code for how the untranslated texts are rendered?

Answer (score 0):

For any text to be translated, make sure you wrap it a translation method depending on where it is used as mentioned here in [DevDocs Translations](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html). Once you do this, make sure translations are present in the translation dictionary CSV. And finally, run this command in your Magento root to deploy localizations: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your custom translation in:

> app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/pt_BR.csv

```
"Word","New translation"
```

If you want to set translation for specific module, you have to append `,module,Magento_Name`:

Example :

```
"Edit","Editar",module,Magento_Catalog
```

**Important:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` **CONTENT**
- clean `pub/static` **CONTENT**
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`